# Serve gzip html page in node

Tags: express, webpack, compression, gzip, brotli

I use webpack-compression-plugin ta compress all my static files and hml files beforehand to gzip and brotli format. If browser supports it I use brotli, if not gzip and last option is original file. So I would have something like this for example after bundling.

```
bundle.js
bundle.js.gz
bundle.js.br
```

On server I use express-static-gzip to serve static files and everything is working fine. All my client static assets are compressd and served like that.

```
import expressStaticGzip from 'express-static-gzip'
const app: Express = new Express()
process.env.PWD = process.cwd()

app.set('view engine', 'ejs')
app.set('views', path.join(process.env.PWD + '/src/server/views'))

app.use(expressStaticGzip(path.join(process.env.PWD + '/src/dist'), {indexFromEmptyFile: false, enableBrotli: true, maxAge: '1y'}))

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.set('Cache-Control', 'no-cache')
  return next()
})

/* Use server side rendering for first load */
app.use(appRenderer)

// Routes
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.render('index')
})

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`
  Express server is up on port ${PORT}
  Production environment
  `)
})
```

The problem I have is with my html file, root. Although I also have gzip and br version of it, it is not served like that. I make it by bundling server side code. Express compression module doesn't work and I also want static compression. I am not using nginx.
[image]

Comment: Did you happen to find the solution? Otherwise, I'm using https://stackoverflow.com/a/15323082/3241111 This works for me. Don't know, how to use it FOR JUST .html and not for `.js` and `.css` bcoz I don't want server to compress `js` and `css` for SSR on each request

Comment: I didn't find easy solution but I did find one. I used Nginx. With Nginx I can use gzip_static module to serve precompressed static files and regular gzip dynamic mode that compresses just html file on the fly.

Comment: That's nice. Do you compress images as well?

Comment: No, not images. I compress every image before I use it with pthotoshop save for web feature and TinyPNG online so images are already compressed and it is not recomended to gzip them.

Comment: Ah ok... that makes sense.. to compress images before hand using tinypng but when I compress one of my images(51kb) using tinypng, it goes down by just 1.5kB but lighthouse complains for the original image(51kb) to be compressed upto 25% :P I checked `content-type` in request header, which accepts gzip format.. May be I need to read more on this :) Also check answer below in 2 min... I got something working..

Answer (score 1):

With the help of this [plugin](https://github.com/expressjs/compression) and as was suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6370478/express-gzip-static-content/15323082#15323082) I got it working

**My code:**
Ensure that you've pre-gzipped `.js` and `.css` files

```
const checkForHTML = req => {
    const url = req.url.split('.');
    const extension = url[url.length -1];

    if (['/'].indexOf(extension) > -1) {
        return true; //compress only .html files sent from server
    }

    return false;
};

var compress = require('compression');
app.use(compress({filter: checkForHTML}));

const encodeResToGzip = contentType => (req, res, next) => {
    req.url = req.url + '.gz';
    res.set('Content-Encoding', 'gzip');
    res.set('Content-Type', contentType);

    next();
};

app.get("*.js", encodeResToGzip('text/javascript'));
app.get("*.css", encodeResToGzip('text/css'));
```

I wanted compression to happen only for .html because I'm using `.ejs` template, so need to compress .html on runtime. Compressing static files(js/css) using `express compression` isn't good idea because it will do it on every request and those are static files. 
Or else, cache your results as suggested [here](https://nodejs.org/api/zlib.html#zlib_compressing_http_requests_and_responses)

Other solution using nginx, as you posted in your comments also seems nice.

Comment: I'll be sure to try your solution also next time I have a chance. I also forgat to tell that there is a plugin `brotli-compression-plugin`. Brotli is a new standard instead of gzip. Everything should work the same. You have three files .js, .js.gz and .js.br and browser uses it in order from last to first.  You can also serve it with Nginx.I think this is the best way for me. I have .ejs template, bundle, vendor, styles... and every static file is generated with chunkhash and it has Cache header set for 1 year. CONTINUE =>

Comment: Html file has no-cache header so browser contacts it on every load but it caches everything else. If there is a change among static files browser will know since it will contacts html. This way it will download only the file that is changed and use everything else from cache. Not using precompressed gzip but on the fly is beneficial in this case.

Comment: me too using `.ejs` and having `chunkhash` cached `css-js` for 1 year. Not caching index.html.. I don't know how to provide offline support in this case... Also, "Not using precompressed gzip but on the fly..." Meaning, in which case? I'm having precached css-js which gives me 200(from disk cached) and not  304(Not Modified) which means, precompressed is fine  @Igor-Vuk

Comment: I was talking about .html. All my static files are also giving 200 except .html that gives 304. You can use CDN for offline support.